# Sortable on array of objects not strings

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

How can I use  component when source is not array of string, but rather array of objects?
All examples just show how to sort array of strings. But I want to sort rows from database, so I have at least 2 columns id and title.

```
<kendo-sortable [navigatable]="true" [data]="tasks"></kendo-sortable>

private tasks: Task[] = [{id: 1, title: "Test 1"}, {id: 2, title: "Test 2"}];
```

I am complete beginner in Angular so accept my apologise, if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a template to your sortable:

```
<kendo-sortable [data]="palettes" >
    <template let-palette="item">
    {{palette.name}}
    </template>
</kendo-sortable>
```

Kendo documentation provides an example for this case :
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/api/SortableComponent/#toc-data

And the related plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3gSg2FnBqiZ7hy2cRzke?p=preview